Why is the area of the coaxial cylinder of $r = x + dx$ given by $2\pi x dx$? Is my professor wrong?
When our Physics Professor gave the lecture about Poiselle's equation, he gave us a derivation of the equation.
When he considered a coaxial cylinder of radius $x + dx$, he wrote its cross-sectional area to be $2\pi x dx$, taking into consideration both the sides of the cylinder of the capillary tube whose thickness is $dx$.
However, shouldn't the value be $2\pi (x + dx)^2$ from the equation of the cross sectional area of a cylinder.
I asked the professor, who told me to wait and said that he would ask the writer of the book he taught us from, but he said that it was correct but did not give an explanation on how it was correct to my satisfaction. Is there something I am missing here?

Does "2 x pie x x x dx" mean $2\pi,x,dx$ ? If so, that's the area of an annulus with inner radius $x$ and thickness $dx$.

can you please explain/expand more on this? I cannot fully understand

I checked this again on paper and it seems that we are using approximation and considering a dx component to be negligible so we get the answer. Thank you, the thought of approximation did not cross my mind

I would guess your prof is considering the flow through a cylindrical shell with inner radius $x$ and thickness $dx$:

so they are considering the flow in the region between the two dashed circles.
The cross sectional area of this region is the area of the larger circle minus the area of the smaller circle:
$$ dA = \pi (x + dx)^2 - \pi x^2 = 2\pi xdx + \pi dx^2 $$
However if $dx \ll x$ the term $dx^2 \ll x\,dx$ and it can be ignored. then we get:
$$ dA \approx 2\pi xdx $$

Thank you. we were not told about the approximation and it did not cross my mind so I was confused
